# Angular (6) form choose selected item in select after http get

Tags: angular, select

I want to **choose an option in form select**, but I don't find the way to do it.

I've check many similar issues on the web but didn't find a way to adapt the solutions to my code.

Here is the view :

```
        <select class="form-control" #selectedValue name="selectedSalles" 
                id="selectedSalles" [(ngModel)]="selectedSalle" 
                (ngModelChange)="addSalleToSelected($event)">
          <option *ngFor="let salle of allSalleEtb | async" 
                [ngValue]="salle" [value]="selectedSalle" >
            {{salle.nom}}
          </option>
        </select>
```

With this code, **The first item of the list `allSalleEtb` gets selected, but it should be another one**.

**If I don't use this `[value]="selectedSalle", nothing get selected and the select is blank**.

I get the "salle" object from :

```
public getSlot(){
  this.creneauService.getSlot(this.idEtablissement, this.idCreneau)
    .subscribe((data: CourseSlot) => {
      this.selectedSalle = data.salle;
    }
  );
}
```

For more informations :

the object "salle" contains "nom" and "id" attributes :

```
salle:Object {idSalle: 2, nom: "110A"}
```

The controller receive informations from a httpClient get request :

```
getSlot(idEtablissement: number, idCreneau: number){
  const url =  environment.API_URL + "/etablissement/" + idEtablissement + "/creneaux/" + idCreneau;
  return  this.httpClient.get(environment.API_URL + "/etablissement/" + idEtablissement + "/creneaux/" + idCreneau);
}
```

Thanks a lot for help if any !!

----------- Edited

When I change the value of "salle" `(ngModelChange)="addSalleToSelected($event)"` , SelectedSalle is edited, and used to post the form :

```
addSalleToSelected(salle){ 
  this.salle = salle;
  this.selectedSalle = salle;
  console.log("salle added"); 
  console.log(salle);
}
```

With all my tentatives, I forgot and deleted `[ngValue]="salle"` in option that is needed, so I put it back.

Comment: Does `selectedSalle` refer to an instance of `salle` found in the `allSallEtb` list? Or is it a separate instance that contains the same values as one item in the list?

Comment: You are always setting `[value] = selectedSalle`, which means the same value for all the options.

Comment: @ConnorsFan **selectedSalle** is the value of selected item. I've edited my post to show the method. @Amit-Chigadabi I used [value] to try to select the item but it doesn't work. I've put back `[ngValue]="salle"` wich I deleted by mistake but is needed.

Comment: Just use `[value]="salle"` and remove `[ngvalue]` attribute from option element. Because selected value will be set to `ngModel` variable `selectedSalle`

Comment: I discover a problem I didn't see. When I load the page with informations to edit, "salle" is a correct object. **If I change the value of "salle", it becomes "[object Object]" and not a real object anymore.**. I've removed [ngvalue].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HTML** *assign `id` in value of option rather than complete object*

```
<select class="form-control" #selectedValue name="selectedSalles" 
        id="selectedSalles" [(ngModel)]="selectedSalle" 
        (ngModelChange)="addSalleToSelected($event)">
    <option *ngFor="let salle of allSalleEtb" [value]="salle.idSalle"> //==== assign id in value rather than complete object
        {{salle.nom}}
    </option>
</select>
```

**TS**

```
public getSlot(){
    this.creneauService.getSlot(this.idEtablissement, this.idCreneau)
            .subscribe((data: CourseSlot) => {
                this.allSalleEtb = data.salle; // set all data here
                this.selectedSalle = this.allSalleEtb[0].idSalle; // set first as selected
            });
}
```

*find selected object on the basis of id*

```
addSalleToSelected(value){ 
    this.salle = this.allSalleEtb.find(salle => salle.idSalle == value); // find selected object by finding in original data by ID
}
```

Working [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/select-value)

Comment: Thanks a lot (even if I shouldn't write it). I solved my problem that was primary from the "salle" list impossible to select. It's solved. Then adding your code was like wonderful strawberry !